# Checking folders different than inbox using poplib in Python

Tags: python, email, imaplib, poplib

Some time ago I ve written a Python script, using poplib library, which retrieves messages from my pop3 email account. Now I would like to use it to retrieve emails from different mail server which works with IMAP. It works well, but only to retrieve messages from **Inbox**. Is there any way to also get emails from other folders like **Spam**, **Sent** etc? I know I could use imaplib and rewrite the script, but my questions is if it's possible to obtain that with poplib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

POP is a single folder protocol.  It is very simple and was not designed for multiple folders.

You will need to use IMAP or other advanced protocols to access additional folders.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer I was looking for.